# Problem finding precompiled libraries on Windows with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, cygwin, ncurses

So I'm currently trying to compile my c++-program (originally written on Linux) on windows. As it is using ncurses, I'm compiling in a cygwin-terminal, where I have the ncurses libs installed:

```
cygcheck -c | grep curses
libncurses++w10          6.1-1.20190727     OK
libncurses-devel         6.1-1.20190727     OK
libncursesw10            6.1-1.20190727     OK
ncurses                  6.1-1.20190727     OK
```

Also, it's using [aubio](https://aubio.org/download#win), so I downloaded and extracted the precompiled binaries to `C:\aubio` and added `C:\aubio\bin` to PATH (where the binaries and the .dll are located).

CMake works fine:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 17" ..
```

But when compiling with:

```
cmake --build . --target dissonance --config Debug
```

I get the following errors (among others that I can handle myself):

```
 fatal  error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "aubio/aubio.h": No such file or directory
 fatal  error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "curses.h": No such file or directory
```

While all libraries previously installed with conan where found, obviously, aubio and ncurses libraries are not found. My problem is that I'm mainly not 100% sure what I did wrong, is it either

1. CMake not being configured correctly to find the libraries on windows
2. or did I miss some steps when "installing" aubio and ncurses.

**So my question is whether someone can either point me in the direction, where the problem might lie (is it 1. or 2.)
Or someone even spotted either a) a missing step after installing the ncurses cygwin-package or while installing the precompiled aubio package or b) something missing/ wrong in my CMakeLists.txt.**

I'm assuming that the problem is quite independent of aubio and it could technically be any other precompiled library.

Here is a slightly reduced version of my CMakeList.txt (everything left out is noted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
# set the project name and version
project(dissonance VERSION 1.0)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
if(APPLE)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread -ldl -lm")
elseif(MSVC)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread -ldl -lm -lncursesw -lcurses")
else()
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Werror -pthread -ldl -lm -lncursesw")
endif(APPLE)
add_compile_options(-fdiagnostics-color=always)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Add source files needed for tests and game
set(SRC_FILES
  [ removed for readility] 
)

# Add soruce files needed for game only
set(SRC_FILES_GAME 
  src/main.cc 
  ${SRC_FILES}
)

include_directories(/usr/local/lib/)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)

add_executable(dissonance ${SRC_FILES_GAME})

target_link_libraries(dissonance PUBLIC aubio curses ncurses ${CONAN_LIBS})

target_include_directories(dissonance PUBLIC "src")
```

I'm aware that I don't need to include `curses` and `ncurses` in the `target_link_libraries` and that adding `-lncursesw -lcurses` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not helping (just stuff I found while searching answers, but apparently it did not work. Leaving it here so people can see).

Here's the link to the github-project, For full code access: [dissonance](https://github.com/georgbuechner/dissonance/tree/mvc).

**EDIT**: Since on Linux the aubio libraries (`libaubio.so`, `libaubio.so.5` ...) are located at `/usr/share/lib/`, which is (obviously not the case in Windows), I changed the following lines:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)
```

to now point to the locations where aubio and ncurses are:

```
include_directories(C:/cygwin64/lib/ C:/aubio/bin/)
link_directories(C:/cygwin64/lib/ C:/aubio/bin/)
```

However, this didn't change anything :D

Comment: are you mixing Windows and Cygwin libraries ? It will not work

Comment: @matzeri Hmm, what exactly do you mean by cygwin libraries? I assumed that these libraries are in .dll format, and can thus count as windows-libraries. 
However, I must admit that I'm confused by the naming:  `libncursesw.dll.a` (cygwin) what's the `.a` doing? aubio is: `libaubio-5.dll` everything installed with conan is also `.dll`.